# Export data to a file using apex

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, data-export

I have a requirement to

1. Run SELECT query on custom object
2. export the data to csv file
3. Automate / schedule step-1 and step-2 .

I know how to achieve step-3, by using apex scheduler class. But I couldn't find anything on exporting data from apex code. We have been using Jitterbit, but now our client wants to get rid of it, and use only salesforce.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're concerned about time or memory limits, use a batch class. This is how I would perform the export of a potentially unknown size (10k+ records).

```
global class X implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    string[] Lines;

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        lines = new String[0];
        return Database.getQueryLocator( your-query-here );
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, SObject[] scope) {
        for(Sobject record: scope) {
            String line = '';
            // build your csv line here
            lines.add(line);
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.batchablecontext bc) {
        String finalResults = String.join(lines, '\n');
        lines = null; // Free temp memory to avoid heap errors
        // proceed to send attachment by email
    }
}
```

The best performance I've gotten for a synchronous export (that is, a direct query, plus processing about 30 fields per record) is about 5,000 records before a CPU timeout exception, so if this is a concern, definitely go with a batch. If you're confident that you can beat the timeout, you could perform the query and translation directly in the scheduler class itself without resorting to a batch.